# Visual Studio C#, WPF controls

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2008, wpf-controls

I'm making a simple program in Visual Studio C# for school and I'm using the WPF Controls. I'm making some type of monthly  report that I need to visualize in a table with the columns that represent the days. 
The problem is that I don't know which control to use. I tried with with the ListBox but it does not give a good result to me. 
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you either want a datagrid, or an itemscontrol with a custom paneltemplate and itemstemplate.

Edit: If you aren't serious about learning WPF, stick with winforms, the learning curve is far easier.  If you want to do any serious user interface work tho, keep working to learn WPF.

Comment: +1 for good advice! WPF is quite a bit tougher to learn, in my opinion (especially if you want to follow good practices...), but it's incredibly powerful.

Comment: If you have the knowledge and patience, there's nothing you can't do, but the same can be said about any toolset (mostly)

Comment: And if you are serious about WPF, inhale the MVVM pattern!

Answer (score 2):

So if I understand correctly you need a grid.
If you use .net 4 you got a build in DataGrid
If not download it from wpf toolkit or consider the use of listview with the view of a grid view